# Почему я вижу layout во время useFetch? nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue3

Есть страница /catalog/category/[code1c].vue
Есть функция

```
    const {data: currentCategory, pending, error, refresh} = await useAsyncData(
        'currentCategory',
        () => $fetch(`https://example.api.com/api/stock/categories/by_1c_id/${code1c}/`,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": basicAuthHeader,
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
    );


    if (!currentCategory.value) {
        throw createError({
            statusCode: error.value.statusCode,
            statusMessage: error.value.statusMessage,
            fatal: true
        });
    }

    return currentCategory.value;
}
```

На странице в script setup получаю заведомо неверную категорию, но если запрос длится долго(~900ms) то layout успевает отобразиться, а только потом уже выдать 404.

`const currentCategory = await getCategoryBy1cId(route.params.code1c);`

Подскажите, может есть какой то префетч или что-то не правильно делаю?

Использую nuxt 3